# Бинарный поиск и побитовый сдвиг

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть реализация алгоритма бинарного поиска.
Зачем тут побитовый сдвиг и ref в параметрах?

```
public static int binarySearch(ref int[] x, int searchValue, int left, int right)
{
    if (right < left)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (left + right) >> 1;
    if (searchValue > x[mid])
    {
        return binarySearch(ref x, searchValue, mid + 1, right);
    }
    else if (searchValue < x[mid])
    {
        return binarySearch(ref x, searchValue, left, mid - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return mid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(right + left) >> 1` тоже самое что `(right + left) / 2` так как в общем случае

`a >> x == a / 2^x`

у вас `x = 1` поэтому получается деление на `2`.
`ref` в параметрах, в даном случае не зачем и излишен, так как массивы во многих языках всегда передаются по ссылке (или по указателю как в плюсах)

Answer (score 2):

Побитовый сдвиг в данном случае эквивалентен делению на два.
Вообще ссылка ref нужна, чтобы параметр передавался по ссылке. 
Но тут есть два "но":

1. В шарпе массив и так передается по ссылке
2. В методе массив не изменяется

Прочитав msdn подумал, что возможно это используется для того, чтобы нельзя было вызвать метод для неинициализированного массива.

Comment: Его и без `ref` нельзя для неинициализарованного вызвать :)